# Scilab - How to plot numbers v string

Tags: plot, scilab

Say I have been tracking my weight each month (on and off for a couple of years),
and I want to plot the data, such that:

- the x-axis represents the time. e.g. Jun 2015, Jul 2015, Aug 2015, Sept 2015.
- the y-axis represents the weights. e.g. 75.4, 75.1, 72.6, 71.6

I thought this could be achieved by simply writing:

```
x = ["Jun 2015", "Jul 2015", "Aug 2015", "Sept 2015"];
y = [75.4, 75.1, 72.6, 71.6];

plot(x,y);
```

But this produces an error. How can I approach this?

And on a related note: How can I have a break in the x-axis? Say that I did not weigh myself on some months, and so I want a break in the x-axis to indicate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the axes entities to do that:

```
   n=size(y,"*");
   plot(1:n,y)
   ax=gca();
   x_ticks=ax.x_ticks;
   x_ticks.locations=1:n;
   x_ticks.labels=x;
   ax.x_ticks=x_ticks;
```